# How to link Meteor to Opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, meteor

There is a button in web page in charge of activating the python script. And I used this package [Python-Shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) to run the command. But I had this error, when the button is clicked. I can see the light of webcam turn on and then turn off. Besides, the script can be executed manully in cmd. So any ideas about this?

Error messages

```
W20200409-19:24:18.229(8)? (STDERR) meteor://app/app/app.js:283
W20200409-19:24:18.271(8)? (STDERR)       if (err) throw err;
W20200409-19:24:18.272(8)? (STDERR)                ^
W20200409-19:24:18.273(8)? (STDERR)
W20200409-19:24:18.275(8)? (STDERR) PythonShellError: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
W20200409-19:24:18.276(8)? (STDERR)     at PythonShell.parseError (C:\Users\Yue Qi Dong\Documents\GitHub\attendanceSystem\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:260:21)
W20200409-19:24:18.277(8)? (STDERR)     at terminateIfNeeded (C:\Users\Yue Qi Dong\Documents\GitHub\attendanceSystem\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:139:32)
W20200409-19:24:18.277(8)? (STDERR)     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yue Qi Dong\Documents\GitHub\attendanceSystem\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:131:13)
W20200409-19:24:18.278(8)? (STDERR)     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
W20200409-19:24:18.279(8)? (STDERR)     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
W20200409-19:24:18.279(8)? (STDERR)     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
W20200409-19:24:18.282(8)? (STDERR)     ----- Python Traceback -----
W20200409-19:24:18.282(8)? (STDERR)     File "C:\Users\Yue Qi Dong\face\detect_face.py", line 18, in <module>
W20200409-19:24:18.283(8)? (STDERR)       faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4) {
W20200409-19:24:18.284(8)? (STDERR)   traceback: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n' +
W20200409-19:24:18.284(8)? (STDERR)     '  File "C:\\Users\\Yue Qi Dong\\face\\detect_face.py", line 18, in <module>\r\n' +
W20200409-19:24:18.285(8)? (STDERR)     '    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)\r\n' +
W20200409-19:24:18.285(8)? (STDERR)     "cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\\projects\\opencv-python\\opencv\\modules\\objdetect\\src\\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'\r\n" +
W20200409-19:24:18.286(8)? (STDERR)     '\r\n',
W20200409-19:24:18.286(8)? (STDERR)   executable: 'py',
W20200409-19:24:18.287(8)? (STDERR)   options: null,
W20200409-19:24:18.287(8)? (STDERR)   script: 'C:\\Users\\Yue Qi Dong\\face\\detect_face.py',
W20200409-19:24:18.287(8)? (STDERR)   args: null,
W20200409-19:24:18.288(8)? (STDERR)   exitCode: 1
W20200409-19:24:18.288(8)? (STDERR) }
```

Meteor method

```
Meteor.methods({
  myPythonCall() {
    PythonShell.run('C:/Users/Yue Qi Dong/face/detect_face.py', null, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('finished');
});
   }
});
```

detect_face.py

```
import cv2

flag = 1 
num = 1 

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

    # To capture video from webcam.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

while True:
    # Read the frame
    _, img = cap.read()
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Detect the faces
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    # Draw the rectangle around each face
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        sub_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    # Display
    img_flip=cv2.flip(img,1)
    cv2.imshow('img', img_flip)
    # Stop if escape key is pressed
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == ord('s'):  
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Windows/System32/face/"+ str(num) + ".jpg", sub_face)
        print(cap.get(3)); 
        print(cap.get(4));
        print("success to save"+str(num)+".jpg")
        print("-------------------------")
        num += 1

    elif k==27:
        break

# Release the VideoCapture object
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can give me some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Python newbie so please bear with me.

```
import cv2

flag = 1
num = 1

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/harry/Projects/meteor-app/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# To capture video from webcam.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
...
```

First, I had downloaded `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` from Github and placed it on the same level as the python script because for some reason the script was giving out errors of not being able to find it.

Second, as you can see I'm specifying the full absolute path to the file because if you were to log the path at which the python file is running it'd be `/home/harry/Projects/meteor-app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server` so the python script wouldn't be able to locate the `.xml` file on the same level.

Third, the second value given to `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` is omitted.

Once I made these changes to the python script, the Meteor app was able to run things smoothly. Good luck!